# Manipulating undo state in codemirror

Tags: undo, codemirror

So I'm using CodeMirror, and I'd like a way to omit certain edits from the `undo` state. In particular, I've got a situation where I want one keystroke to

1. Replace a portion of the mirror text AND
2. Auto-indent the fresh region

Doing this naively would mean that using the keystroke, then hitting `undo` would leave the mirror containing the new text without the indentation. I'd like a single `undo` to restore the initial text rather than going to the unindented version of the replaced text.

The only API-supported approach seems to be doing a `.getHistory` call before the indent, followed by a `.setHistory` call immediately afterwards, but [the docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_history) imply that this is a bad idea. Specifically, the effects of this are undefined if the contents of the mirror changed between `.getHistory` and `.setHistory` calls, which is the whole point in this situation.

There's also an `addToHistory` flag in the [text marking API](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_marker), but it's only available marking rather than arbitrary edits like indentation.

Is there a good way to do what I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes made within a single [operation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#operation) will result in only a single history event.

If arranging for a single operation isn't viable, the origin field of a change (settable as an argument to `replaceRange` and `replaceSelection`, and in other cases a little more awkwardly by registering a `beforeChange` event handler) determines the type of history-event-combination that CodeMirror does. If you assign an origin that starts with an asterisk (`*`) character, subsequent changes with the same origin will be combined. If the origin starts with a `+`, subsequent same-origin changes will be combined when they occur within `options.historyEventDelay` milliseconds.

Comment: The `operation` approach works fine for my use case (I just didn't realize that it would cluster history states as well as DOM changes).